# dateTime is changing on frontend application (angularjs 1.x.x)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

My frontend application is running for months, and every thing was ok, until this week, when the problem started. And this problem is only on google chrome, in the firefox, every thing is ok.

My frontend web application use angularjs 1.x, with angularjs $resource to requests and moment to manipulate date.

The problem is with dateTime, apparently the google chrome is changing it in random way. Here is the responsive from backend API (it is correct, UTC)

```
 "Horarios": [
    {
      "CodigoTurma": 2,
      "HorarioInicial": "0001-01-01T10:00:00Z",
      "HorarioFinal": "0001-01-01T10:50:00Z",
      "Inativo": false,
      "CodigoFilial": 14,
      "Filial": null,
      "Id": 2,
    },
    {
      "CodigoTurma": 2,
      "HorarioInicial": "0001-01-01T11:00:00Z",
      "HorarioFinal": "0001-01-01T11:50:00Z",
      "Inativo": false,
      "CodigoFilial": 14,
      "Filial": null,
      "Id": 3,
    }

  ],
```

If i use debugger on browser, to see the response/callback, I can notice that the dateTime is already changed. **Here is the PROBLEM !**

[Print of object response from angular $resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1piuL.png)

The correct dateTime should be

```
"HorarioInicial": "0001-01-01T07:00:00Z" 
"HorarioFinal": "0001-01-01T07:50:00Z"
```

I mean, GMT -3 Because it is my local dateTime, but the application ou browser, I do not know who, is changing to something like

```
"HorarioInicial": "0001-01-01T06:43:00Z" 
"HorarioFinal": "0001-01-01T07:53:00Z"
```

I think that maybe there was a change on chrome javascript engine related to date or something.

My front end stack is:

```
 "angular-input-masks": "^2.3.0",
"angular-sortable-view": "0.0.15",
"autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
"babelify": "^6.1.2",
"browserify": "^13.0.0",
"css-mqpacker": "^5.0.1",
"cssnano": "^3.7.1",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"graceful-fs": "^4.1.3",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.6",
"gulp-fn": "0.0.0",
"gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
"gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
"gulp-postcss": "^6.1.1",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.0.0-alpha",
"gulp-sync": "^0.1.4",
"gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
"gulp-usemin": "^0.3.22",
"model-js": "^0.2.5",
"moment": "^2.14.1",
"open": "0.0.5",
"pluralize-words-ptbr": "https://github.com/keep-faith/pluralize-ptbr.git",
"postcss-import": "^8.1.2",
"postcss-nested": "^1.0.0",
"postcss-simple-vars": "^2.0.0",
"signalr-no-jquery": "^0.1.8",
"through": "^2.3.8",
"vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
"vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
"watchify": "^3.7.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the problem. The API backend was sending the year out of the JavaScript Range (1970), so the google chrome got lost on changing to the local timezone. The FireFox is smart enough to dribble this developer mistake, the Chrome does not.